# Resolving promise data

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Considering code snippet below,

```
function one(){
    var prm = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        resolve("one");
    });
    prm.customKey = function(){
    }
    return prm;
}
function two(){
    var prm = one();
    prm.then(function(res){
        return "two";
    });
    return prm;
}
function three(){
    return one().then(function(res){
        return "two";
    });
}
```

I was hoping the below two would console res as "two" (resolve "two").

But strangely
i) consoles res as "one", 
ii) consoles res as "two"

```
i) two().then(function(res){
       console.log(res);
   });

ii) three().then(function(res){
       console.log(res);
    });
```

Can someone explain why it is behaving like this.

Comment: Well, despite the `then` in function `two`, you don't return there the promise returned by that `then` call, but instead you ignore that `then` return, and return instead the promise returned by `one`, so obviously a `then` on a `two()` will apply to the promise returned by  `one()`. Maybe you thought that a call to `then` would mutate the promise it was called on: this is not true. It *returns* a new promise without affecting the original promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you return prm. 
That's a promise, that returns one.
The place, where you return "two", this return statement is for the function it's called in, that means for the callback inside .then statement.

It doesn't **affect** the promise itself. You just used a promise (from one()) inside your two() method, and returned it **as is**.

Answer (score 0):

In second and third function you should also return new `Promise` that waits for another Promises and resolves its response, something like this:

```
function two(){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      one().then(() => resolve("two"));
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In function **two**, prm variable wasn't actually updated when it was returned by the function.

after this line directly
`var prm = one();`

it jumps to this line
`return prm;`

because it is not expecting to get the data right now from the promise.

However, in the other function **three** you return the promise, so the result pops out as you are expecting.

For **two** to get the same results as **three**, add async and await

```
async function two(){
    var prm = one();
    await prm.then(function(res){
        prm = "two";
    });
    return prm;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying function to this:

```
function two(){
  var prm = one();
  prm.then(function(res){
    return "two";
 });
}
```